# RSA procedure cryptology

Tags: encryption, rsa, maple, prime-factoring, greatest-common-divisor

Hi i was wondering if anyone can help me with the following procedure using maple

The protocol of the rsa decryption/encryption method is below and the question i am trying to attempt after that with my attempt below it, i will appreciate any help. Thanks

[image]

my current attempt is the following

```
rsa := proc (key::rsakey, msg::(list(rsascii))) 
local ct, pe, pm, i; 
 pm := 26271227347; 
pe := key[2]; 
ct := [];
for i to nops(msg) do ct := [op(ct), `mod`(message[i]^pe, pm)] 
end do; 
RETURN(ct) 
end proc;
```

this was from using the maple website

Comment: and...? is there a problem?

Comment: Yeah it runs but when I try to evaluate with the public key and a bit of the cipher text that is in ASCII it doesn't give anything back

Comment: A public key this small permits only ASCII messages of 3 characters.

Comment: yeah the first bit of ciphertext is 11393739244 which in plain text i think is wha or Wha

Answer (score 1):

You've been given `n` and `e`, and you'll need to find the corresponding `d` before you can decode. I don't understand why you were trying to use `e` to decode.

Your procedure contains at least one type, using `message[i]` instead of `msg[i]`. See also comments in the code below.

After finding `d` I get that the encoded integer 11393739244 decodes to the integer 87, which corresponds to the ASCII character "W" (not "wha" or "Wha" as you suggested).

I don't understand what you intend on doing about block size, and *so I've had to guess*. Below I show encoding/decoding done either A) a character at a time, or B) using three characters at once. I trust you realize that encoding one-character-at-a-time isn't a great idea. Also, in a duplicate post in another forum you wrote that you don't care about security against attack. (You also wrote there that this isn't homework, but here it looks like it more, IMO.)

If you had trouble writing and using your `rsa` procedure then you may find the various splitting/concetenating/padding operations tough also.

You wrote in a comment that when you tried to use your initial attempt at procedure `rsa` then, "it doesn't give anything back". If it returned as an unevaluated call then perhaps your attempt at creating the proc and assigning it didn't actually work. If you have trouble using Maple's default 2D Input mode in a Document then consider switching your preferences to 1D Maple Notation input in a Worksheet. Those are two Preferences for Maple's Standard Java GUI.

NB. I use Maple's `numtheory[lambda]` command to find "the smallest integer i such that for all g coprime to n, g^i is congruent to 1 modulo n". In recent Maple versions this is also avaliable as the command `NumberThoery:-CarmichaelLambda`. See also [here](https://oeis.org/A002322).

```
restart;

# The procedure `rsa` below can be used to both encode or
# decode an integer.
#
# Conversion from/to ASCII is done separately, before/after.

rsa := proc(key::list(posint), msg::list(posint)) 
  local ct, pe, pm, i; 
  pm := key[1]; 
  pe := key[2];

  ## The original used `message` instead of `msg`, which was
  ## a careless typo. But iterated list concatenation like this
  ## is inefficient. Better to just use `seq`, as below.
  ## Also, use inert `&^` instead of `^` in the call to `mod`
  ## since the latter inefficiently computes the power
  ## explicitly (before taking the modulus).

  #ct := [];
  #  for i to nops(msg) do ct := [op(ct), `mod`(msg[i] &^ pe, pm)] 
  #end do;

  ct := map(u->`mod`(u &^ pe, pm), msg);

  return ct; 
end proc:

# You supplied (n,e) and you'll need to find d in order to decode.

n:=26271227347;
                          n := 26271227347

L := numtheory[lambda](n);
                          L := 13135445468

e:=11546465;
                            e := 11546465

evalb( e < L ); # a requirement
                                true

evalb( gcd(e, L) = 1); # a requirement
                                true

d := 1/e mod L;
                           d := 7567915453

# Now decode the number you supplied.

res := rsa([n,d],[11393739244]);
                             res := [87]

with(StringTools):
# So what ASCII character is that?

convert(res,bytes);

                                 "W"

s := "Wha":
sb := map(convert,convert(s,bytes),string);
                      sb := ["87", "104", "97"]

sbn := map(parse,sb);
                        sbn := [87, 104, 97]

encoded := rsa([n,e],sbn);
          encoded := [11393739244, 9911682959, 21087186892]

decoded := rsa([n,d],encoded);
                      decoded := [87, 104, 97]

pad := proc(str::string)
  local r;
  r := irem(length(str),3);
  cat(seq("0",i=1..`if`(r=0,0,3-r)), str);
end proc:

map(pad, map(convert,decoded,string));
                        ["087", "104", "097"]

cat(op(map(u->convert(map(parse,[LengthSplit(convert(u,string),3)]),
                      bytes), %)));
                                "Wha"

newsb := [cat(op(map(SubstituteAll,map(PadLeft,sb,3)," ","0")))];
                           newsb := ["087104097"]

newsbn := map(parse,newsb);
                        newsbn := [87104097]

encoded := rsa([n,e],newsbn);
                      encoded := [15987098394]

decoded := rsa([n,d],%);
                        decoded := [87104097]

map(pad, map(convert,decoded,string));
                            ["087104097"]

cat(op(map(u->convert(map(parse,[LengthSplit(convert(u,string),3)]),
                      bytes), %)));
                                "Wha"
```

Comment: If you are using 2D Math (typeset) Input mode then make sure that there is no extra space between `rsa` and the opening bracket `(` when you call it like `rsa(...)`. With an extra space it would be parsed as multiplication.

Comment: hi i completly forgot about needing to calculate d, thanks for that , and for decrypting the messages at one character at a time that would take too much time so i have used the following instead

          block1:=rsa([n,d],[first number to decrypt, second, third, and so on]); 

 can you explain to me what  ct := map(proc (u) options operator, arrow; `mod`(`&^`(u, pe), pm) end proc, msg) is doing its quiet intimidating haha

Comment: Try and figure out whether the candidate `d` is correct. You haven't supplied a significant portion of the encoded message, so you'll have to let us know how it goes...

Comment: the rsa method works the message is correct I was just wondering what that line was doing within the procedure as I don't really understand that but